# Django Function View Skips Loop?

Tags: python, django, apache, django-views, django-class-based-views

In my Bartertown function for some reason it completely skips the if loop. I printed out each variable to show in the logs that the first variable `"Paste"` should have rendered a new page at `domain/Thunderdome/Bartertown` using `thunderdome/paste_form`, when it actually ignores the loop and goes straight to the `return HttpResponse`

**thunderdome/Views**

```
class SquirrelView(View):
    def post (self, request):
        form = request.POST.get("thundersubmit", "")
        if form  == '1':
            request.session["_thundersubmit"] = 'Pool'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Bartertown')
        if form  == '2':
            request.session["_thundersubmit"] = 'Paste'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Bartertown')
        if form  == '3':
            request.session["_thundersubmit"] = 'Upload'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Bartertown')


        return HttpResponseRedirect('home')

def Bartertown(request):
    statusly = request.session.get('_thundersubmit')
    print statusly
    if statusly == 'Paste':
        render(request, 'thunderdome/paste_form.html')
    return HttpResponse(statusly)
```

^^^ Skips the `If` statement, as viewed in the error logs, `'Paste'` should have "hit" that loop and rendered paste_form.html, when what really happened is it skipped the loop and went directly to `return HttpResponse(statusly)`.

**Urls**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app.forms import BootstrapAuthenticationForm
from thunderdome.views import SquirrelView, Bartertown

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', 'app.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', 'app.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^Thunderdome', include('thunderdome.urls')),
    url(r'^Thunderdome/squirrel', SquirrelView.as_view()),
    url(r'^Thunderdome/Bartertown', 'thunderdome.views.Bartertown'),
```

**thunderdome/test_forms.html**

```
                <form id="checkout-form" class="smart-form" novalidate="novalidate" action="/Thunderdome/squirrel" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset>
                        <section>
                            <div class="well">
                                <button type="submit" name="thundersubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  value = "1">
                                    Choose Pool
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" name="thundersubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value = "2">
                                    Paste-A-Config
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" name="thundersubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value = "3">
                                    Upload-A-Config
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

**Error Log:**

```
[Mon Feb 09 08:48:50 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 09 08:48:57 2015] [error] Paste
[Mon Feb 09 08:49:00 2015] [error] Pool
[Mon Feb 09 08:49:02 2015] [error] Paste
```

**Access Log:**

```
10.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:08:49:00 -0600] "GET /Thunderdome/Bartertown HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "http://10.0.0.2/Thunderdome" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:08:49:01 -0600] "GET /Thunderdome HTTP/1.1" 200 30140 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:08:49:02 -0600] "POST /Thunderdome/squirrel HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://10.0.0.2/Thunderdome" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:08:49:02 -0600] "GET /Thunderdome/Bartertown HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "http://10.0.0.2/Thunderdome" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
```

**Why is this happening? I am missing something about function based views vs class based views?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually return the `HttpResponse` generated by the `render` statement inside the if block. Try changing:

```
if statusly == 'Paste':
    render(request, 'thunderdome/paste_form.html')
```

to:

```
if statusly == 'Paste':
    return render(request, 'thunderdome/paste_form.html')
```

As you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), the `render` method returns a `HttpResponse` object. You are discarding that response and falling through to the `return HttpResponse(statusly)` statement.

Comment: Two responses enter, one response leaves. etc. Nice naming scheme

Comment: Glad it's obvious Matthew!